# How to set proper layout with both large screen and small screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

iTunes Connect just rejected my iPhone application because it did not follow one of the App Store Review Guidelines, the **2.4.1** about Hardware Compatibility:

> To ensure people get the most out of your app, iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible. We encourage you to consider building universal apps so customers can use them on all of their devices. [...]

So setting *iPhone* in *Deployment info* is not enough because I just found out that an iPhone app will run on iPad anyway, but the screen dimension will be resized drastically.

iTunes Connect sent me a screenshot while they were testing on iPad: I don't know what model it was or if it was a simulated device but the screen size was very small, at least in comparison to the one I work with in my Storyboard (iPhone 7s).

I added the iPhone 4s simulator in my Xcode and ran the app: the screen size was just the same as the one in the testing iPad from iTunes Connect, so I may try to adjust my layout with iPhone 4s.

I made my app with an iPhone 7s screen in the Storyboard; I started learning about Auto Layout and its features, so that it would adjust automatically; the main problem is the following...

Even if I have a correct Auto Layout, how can I modify my UI elements from a 7s screen to a 4s screen? For example, in my login view I have the header logo, the username and password textboxes, the Login button and the logo footer: they are just too many UI elements for a 4s screen! I should shrink all of them but they would be troublesome.

What would be a good approach for making a good layout for both large screens (7s) and small ones (4s / resized screen on iPad)? Detect from code on what phone model the app is running and dynamic adjust the layout? I'd prefer to not modify layout with Swift, I work well with Storyboard. How can I handle so many UI elements that fit in large screens but collapse each other or disappear in small screens?

Answer (score 1):

Either you can reduce the height of each element and space between them for particular screen size's(iPhone 4/Iphone 5) by modifying autolayout constraints at run time or you can use Scroll Views .In that case your whole content won't be visible completely.